# Declare Generic static method in C#

Tags: c#, .net

Is there any way to declare a generic static method in C#?
For example:

```
public static class Class<T,P> 
    where T:class
    where P:class
{

    public static T FromTtoP (this P ob)
    {
    ...
    }

}
```

this code does not work .
I want to map from DTO to DAL and and vice-versa.

I have tried making the class non-generic

```
public static class Class
{

    public static TDTO MapToDTO<TDTO, TDAL>(this TDAL dal)
                where TDTO : class
                where TDAL : class
            {

            }
}
```

I get an error message from "this".

Comment: What do you mean by _does not work_? You get any exception or error message? Can you please be more specific about your problem?

Comment: Why do you think generics are a solution to your problem? And why are you using extension methods to accomplish that?

Comment: You're not declaring a generic method - you're declaring a generic *class* at the moment.

Comment: Re the edit and "i get error message from `this`": that compiles for me; are you using a recent C# compiler? Also: saying "this core does not work" and "I get an error message" is *kinda* not helpful. Full descriptions of what happens (including copy and paste of any messages etc) is much more useful.

Comment: I see what you are doing there! But I can tell you to pay attention. If the DTO is used across layers and the DAL is just one layer, then the DTO [should be an abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), more like an interface. I know this may add to the confusion but you are trying to do something well-documented and conceptually not easy. Welcome to OO design :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't have an extension method in a generic class. Instead, make the method generic, and keep the class non-generic.

For example:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
  public static T ConvertToT<T, P>(this P ob)
    where T : class
    where P : class
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Of course, this will not really work well - there's no way to infer the arguments for the method call, which makes this kind of useless.

Comment: The important part here is to not forget to add `<T, P>` after the method name, like `Convert<T, P>`.

Answer (score 1):

@luaan I disagree on the "kind of useless" part.
We used it to create a generic mapper in a base controller class, and it's super helpful:

```
    public static DTOClass MightyMap<DTOClass, SourceClass>(SourceClass obj)
        where DTOClass : class
        where SourceClass : class
    {
        var dto = (DTOClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(DTOClass));
        dto.InjectFrom(obj); //Using Omu.ValueInjecter
        return dto;
    }
```

Used like this:

```
IQueryable<MyEntity> query = somequery;    
var mappedItems = (await query.Select(f=> MightyMap<MyDTO, MyEntity>(f)).ToListAsync());
```